# How to Render Blocks of different sizes on desktop and Mobile

Tags: magento-1.9

Please refer this url:
https://www.unnatisilks.com/

These guys are rendering one sets of Home page blocks on desktop and the same images with 2 row alignment on mobile

How can I achieve this?

I also want to know how to get blocks per row with complete width on mobile just like this page:
https://www.unnatisilks.com/sarees-online.html

Please help
I see that this site is built on Magento
So is their a custom plugin which can help?

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

This is done using CSS.

Specifically on their site they're using Media queries to define their grid widths.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.hpgrid_4:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
```

This means that on a screen size with a maximum width of 767px the div with this class will be 49% width.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.hpgrid_4:nth-of-type(2n) {
    float: right;
    width: 49%;
}
```

See nth of type css rules to understand what's happening here, every 2nd row will be assigned the value of float right.

Compare to their desktop styles

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1281px)
.container_12 .hpgrid_4 {
    width: 307px;
}
```

The width is hardcoded to be 307 px, so that 3 items can fit on each row.

This topic is a bit too broad to explain in one reply, so I'll refer you to a [Responsive Web Design guide](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp).

I'd recommend using the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) library, as it's classes have responsive web design built in.